# Parameterized Java Types (Generics)

Tags: java, type-systems, generics, parameters, type-safety

Consider this "legacy" code:

```
public interface IPersistentCollection {
    IPersistentCollection cons(Object o);
}
```

Genericized in Java, it could become something like this:

```
public interface IPersistentCollection<T> {
    IPersistentCollection<T> cons(T o);
}
```

Clearly adding a new item to a mutable Java collection shouldn't change the type of the existing collection.  But unlike the Java collections, cons() returns a completely new, immutable collection, leaving the old collection unchanged, opening the possibility that it could meaningfully take on a different type than the original collection had.

1. Obviously, you should be able to cons an object of type Ford to a collection of Cars and get a collection of Cars back (covariance).  I think this is covered by the above generic example.
2. If Car and Train both extended a Vehicle class, it would be handy to be able to cons a Train to a collection of Cars and get a collection of Vehicles back (contravariance).  How would I even write that?  I thought by declaring new bounded type variables, S and E for "Vehicle" and "Train" in this example:

   ```
   // Illegal because of <S super T>
   <S super T, E extends S> IPersistentCollection<S> cons(E o);

   // Simpler, but still Illegal because java disallows <S super T>
   <S super T> IPersistentCollection<S> cons(S o);
   ```
3. If we want to assume that the programmer knows what they are doing, you should be allowed to cons something totally unrelated to a collection and get a collection of Objects back.  I think this is the extreme case of contravariance, but I'm not sure there is even a name for it ("Dynamic Language" maybe?).

I think that if #2 were legal, it would cover cases #1 and #3.

My questions are:

A. To what degree is it possible to do #2 in Java?

B. Is #2 possible/easier in other languages?  Scala?  Haskell? ML?

C. In theory, a type system that preferred the most specific version of S in example 2 could handle a definition like this.  What book can I read about type systems without a PHD in math?  Is "Types and Programming Languages" by Pierce the best place to start?

Sample code would be appreciated.  If I'm using terms like covariance and contravariance incorrectly, I would appreciate being politely corrected.

Comment: #3 is just ordinary contravariance. You up the type parameter of the return type to the most specific common super type; for two "totally unrelated" classes the most specific common super type is `Object`.

Comment: the compiled code would be the same

Comment: If both Car and Train both implement interfaces Vehicle and PurchasableItem, which type would a concatenation of cars and trains become?

Comment: @PeteKirkham `<T extends Vehicle & PurchasableItem>`, but Java is quite limited in how this can be used.

Comment: @ggovan that's a constraint, but the resulting IPersistentCollection must have a concrete type

Comment: @Pete, probably in that situation the compiler would flag an ambiguity and require the programmer to explicitly specify the result type.

Comment: #2 -> `IPersistenceCollection<Vehicle> col = new Implementation<Vehicle>(); col.cons(myCar);`

Comment: @PeteKirkham Great question, several great answers.  The most specific common ancestor of both Vehicle and PurchasableItem would be another reasonable choice, even if that was `Object`.

Comment: This was really helpful toward answering my question: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ107

Answer (score 2):

Scala's `List`s work this way for the `::` (cons) and `++` (concat) operators, but not for `+`, `:+`, and `+:` (which is okay because that's sometimes what you want).  The type signature looks like:

```
::[B >: T](x: B): List[B]

// Returns a List[Any] (Any is Scala's "Object" type)
5 :: List("example")
```

This says `B` is a superclass of `T`, the type of the List you're consing onto.  You're consing a `B` element and returning a `List` of `B`s.

Let's say `T` is a `Car` and `B` is a `Vehicle`.  The `x` parameter can be any subclass of `Vehicle` due to covariance, so you don't need to specify a third type.  I don't know Java's type system as well, but I imagine its equivalent (if it's supported) would be:

```
<B super T> IPersistentCollection<B> cons(B o);
```

Answer (score 1):

Angelika Langer is my new hero.  She has an incredible Java Generics FAQ
http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ107

1. She had the insight "`class Box<T super Number> {...}` is not permitted"... and "conjunctions with method declarations, type parameters with a lower bound would occasionally be useful."  Wow!  A.) I'm not wasting my time trying the impossible and B.) there is a chance that what I'm trying to do might be useful!
2. She suggests the workaround of using a static method as follows:

   ```
   static <A, B, X extends A, Y extends B>
           B addToMap(Pair<X,Y> pair, Map<A,B> map) {
       return map.put(pair.first,pair.second);
   }
   ```

I was able to apply that directly to a static method in my interface, which worked!

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <S, E extends S, T extends S> Consable<S> cons(Consable<T> cs, E e) {
    return Consable3.of((S) e, (Consable<S>) cs);
}
```

For a short time I thought that this same technique can be applied to an instance method, but it cannot:

```
public static interface Consable<T> {
    // T is the type of our existing collection (defined above)
    // E is the new element being cons-ed with our collection
    // S is a super-type of both T and E and therefore the
    //   type of our new collection.
    <S, E extends S, T extends S> Consable<S> cons(E e);
}

...

class Animal {}
class Mammal extends Animal {}

...

// Consable<Vehicle> vehicles = cars.cons(new Train());
Consable<Animal> vehicles = cars.cons(new Mammal());
```

Commenting out cons-ing things to the vehicles, That compiles!  Eek!  And runs!

```
$ javac -Xlint JavaConsSignature.java 
$ java JavaConsSignature
JavaConsSignature$Mammal@15db9742
JavaConsSignature$Car@6d06d69c
JavaConsSignature$Chevy@7852e922
JavaConsSignature$Chevy@4e25154f
JavaConsSignature$Chevy@70dea4e
```

So static method: Good.  Instance method: Bad.  It doesn't support fluent interface building, but at least you can have this particular kind of type safety on some kind of method in Java.